# Calculate revenue from the margin and profit

Tags: arithmetic

Let's say I have a profit of $50$ and a margin of $50\%$.

Now I know that the revenue is $150$, despite not knowing the cost, because this is the only possibility for the $50\%$ margin i.e.

$Cost * (1 + Margin) = Revenue$

$100 * (1 + 0.5) = 150$

Now, what would the formula be to get the revenue by just knowing the $50\%$ margin and the $50$ profit?

Comment: Does COGS mean Cost?

Comment: Yes, Cost Of Goods Sold

Comment: Ok.  Well, letting C=Cost, R=Revenue.  Then the Margin is $R-C$ so you'd have $R-C=50$ and $R-C=\frac C2$.  Can you finish from there?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get what you're aiming at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let ...

- $c$ represent Cost
- $m$ represent Margin
- $r$ represent Revenue
- $p =r-c$ represent Profit

Your formula is
$$c(1+m)=r$$
you want to express this using $p$ instead of $c$

so substitute $(r-p)$ for $c$
$$(r-p)(1+m) = r$$

now isolate $r$
$$r(1+m)-r = p(1+m) $$
obtain the result
$$ r = p\bigg(\frac{1+m}m  \bigg ) =  p \left ( 1+\frac 1m \right )$$

in your case $m=0.5$ so $\frac 1m = 2$ and you get
$$ r = 50(1+2)=150  $$

Comment: Oh your formula is better than the one I posted. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I found an old calculation of mine. The formula is:

$$\begin{align} Revenue = \frac{Profit}{1 - \frac{1}{1 + Margin}}\end{align}$$

Comment: That is the same formula that I got in a different form

Comment: Yes, way cleaner than mine. Thank you.

Comment: I strongly recommend that whenever you want to do algebra, name your variables as single letters rather than words, it makes it much easier to see the mathematical structure of a formula. 

I find it quite shocking how much more difficult it is to do algebra with words instead of letters, it feels almost like a right handed person trying to write with their left hand.